# Detecting cookie authentication in ASP.NET CORE / MVC with Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core with EntityFramework backed Identity.

I'm able to log users when they use the login-form of the site, but I have a situation where I also need to detect user authentication via the "remember me" cookie mechanism, i.e. this line of code, which sets the `isPersistant` flag to true if the user cheks "remember me" in the login form:

```
result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

In the old system this was done in Global.asax by overriding these methods:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest() { }
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() { }
protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest() { }
```

... but I assume I'll need to implement this as some kind of middleware component in CORE, but I'm not sure what to look for after that.

Ultimately, in this scenario, I need to log "Last Login Time", so I don't want to detect authentication for every request.  Perhaps it is necessary to somehow tie this to the active session?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "remember me"? this flag is part of the auth cookie.

Comment: Are you using EF Identity?

Comment: @trailmax updated question

Comment: @nurdyguy Yes, I am useing EF Identity.

Comment: So if the user hits your site and already has the cookie, you want to log this?  The `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` flag should tell you if they are authenticated or not.